# How to have partial search return results with a single column then have the results clickable to show entire row of that result?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Ok, I am going to try to explain this as best as I can. I created a search for a database that has 3 columns: Category, OEM Number, and Price. I want to make so that when the user inputs an OEM number it will show the category and OEM Number as the result, then the results are clickable to show the entire row, Category, OEM Number, and Price. I also want it so that if they only input a partial OEM Number, that it will list all the OEM Numbers that include that partial number and they click the correct full OEM Number they want to display the Category, OEM Number, and Price for that OEM Number. Here is my code as of now, it just has them input an OEM Number and returns the entire row or if they input a partial number it returns all results including that partial number all on the page. I want the page that shows the price to only have a single entry on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>AJAX Search Example</title>
    <script>
    function fetch() {
      // (A) GET SEARCH TERM
 
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
      data.append('ajax', 1);

      // (B) AJAX SEARCH REQUEST
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
      // (CHANGE1) USING ONREADYSTATECHNAGE INSTEAD OF ONLOAD
      
    xhr.onreadystatechange =  function (event) {
        // (CHANGE2) we will check if ajax process has completed or not it goes from 1,2,3,4 means end. 

if(this.readyState == 4){

// (CHANGE2) when ready state comes to 4 we then check what response status was it if it is 200 good else error. 

if(this.status == 200){
    // (CHANGE3) MOVED ALL YOUR CODE HERE 

// (CHANGE4) we need to use responseText instead of response because JSON comes as string that is why we are parsing it to be converted into array

var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    //I have added just a measure to check what the out put is you can remove it latter. open dev console to get the result.
    console.log(results);

wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
wrapper.innerHTML = "";
var rows = "";
    if (results.length > 0) {

// (CHANGE5) UPDATED data ref with results 

for (i = 0; i <  results.length; i++) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
              //it is just as simple to create id only it must start with alaphabet not number 

line.id=`res${[i]}`;

//we created span tag to display price and this is what we will change. on that span we will create a data-price attribute which will hold orginial price and we will run claulcations using that number 

//BIG CHANGE
//BIG CHANGE

//since after parsing invidual record will be in Js object so we dont need to access them like array  results[i]['item']

//we access them with dot notation results[i].item

rows += `<tr id=res${[i]}><td>${results[i].category}</td><td>${results[i].oemnumber}</td><td>$<span data-price='${results[i].price}'>${results[i].price}</span>
            select discount >>   
            <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a> <a href="#50">100%</a></td></tr>`; 
          }
          wrapper.innerHTML = `<table class="table">
    <thead><th>Category</th><th>OEM</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody>${rows}</tbody></table>`;
 // (CHANGE6) We moved event listeners here so any newly added elements will be updated. 

 //get all the links and apply event listener through loop   
 
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      

      for ( ii = 0; ii <  links.length; ii++) {
         links[ii].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         
       //capture link value and get number to be converted to percentage  
       
       var percentage = event.target.innerText.match(/\d+/)[0]/100;
 
 //capture the data-price which is within same div as anchor link
 
 var pricetarget = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('[data-price]');
 
 //get value of data-price
 
 var actualprice=  pricetarget.dataset.price;
 
 //run math and chnage the value on display
 
 pricetarget.innerHTML=(actualprice*percentage).toFixed(2);
      
      
      });
      }

        } else { wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found"; }

 } else {
 
 //if reponse code is other ethan 200 

alert('INTERNET  DEAD OR AJAX FAILED ');

 }

 }
       

            

      };

// (CHANGE7) We moved open event to end so everything is ready before it fires.

xhr.open('POST', "2-search.php");
      xhr.send(data);
      return false;

 
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form ID='myForm' onsubmit="return fetch();">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR CATALYTIC CONVERTER</h1>
      <input type="text" id="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <!-- (B) SEARCH RESULTS -->
    <div id="results"></div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

To sum it up simply, I want to have the first results return just 2 columns in the results, the category and the OEM Number. Then I want those results to be clickable and return the entire single row, all 3 columns. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: what have you tried to accomplish this? Where was it failing? How can we test it?

Comment: The code I posted is what I have done so far. I am not sure how to make the results clickable and was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. Would it be as simple as having it return just the category and oem number columns in the results and then doing something like onclick function to show the entire row? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling a global function `fetch`, and there is a built in browser function also called [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that's like a much much better `XMLHttpRequest`.

Let's rename that `fetch` function to `getData`, to save confusion.

Next up it's getting data and trying to update your DOM, which makes it much harder to debug and find out what it's doing wrong.

You're setting `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML`, which will work, but will also cause fairly slow reflows. You may want to set DOM directly or use a library like Lit or React (or any of the many others) that will handle that for you.

By replacing the AJAX fetch with dummy data I can test this, and it works in a snippet...

```js
async function getData() {
  // (A) GET SEARCH TERM

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
  data.append('ajax', 1);

  const wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
  wrapper.innerHTML = "Loading...";

  // This is the better API to use
  //const response = await fetch(...);
  //if(!response.ok) return;
  //const results = await response.json();

  // But let's use a dummy
  const results = [{
      category: 'foo',
      oemnumber: 1,
      price: 1
    },
    {
      category: 'bar',
      oemnumber: 2,
      price: 2
    }
  ];

  let rows = "";
  if (results.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      let line = document.createElement("div");
      line.id = `res${[i]}`;

      rows += `<tr id=res${[i]}><td>${results[i].category}</td><td>${results[i].oemnumber}</td><td>$<span data-price='${results[i].price}'>${results[i].price}</span>
            select discount >>   
            <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a> <a href="#50">100%</a></td></tr>`;
    }

    wrapper.innerHTML = `<table class="table">
    <thead><th>Category</th><th>OEM</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody>${rows}</tbody></table>`;

    const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    for (ii = 0; ii < links.length; ii++)
      links[ii].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        const percentage = event.target.innerText.match(/\d+/)[0] / 100;
        const pricetarget = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('[data-price]');

        const actualprice = pricetarget.dataset.price;

        pricetarget.innerHTML = (actualprice * percentage).toFixed(2);
      });

  } else
    wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found";
};

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  getData();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
<form ID='myForm'>
  <h1>SEARCH FOR CATALYTIC CONVERTER</h1>
  <input type="text" id="search" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<!-- (B) SEARCH RESULTS -->
<div id="results"></div>
```

It sounds like you're describing a master-detail-list, where selecting a row shows a detail panel with more information. Generally you want to split this out so that the detail is rendered outside the result list, as you reset the result list all the time.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that when it shows the price for an item it only has one item in the list, rather than multiple items in the list. As of now, say the number they are looking up is "25325539", if you only type "5539" into the search box, it will return results for "25325539, 55398190AB, 5539882AB, 55398882AB, 55398883AC" with all the information for each. I want it to just show the category and OEM Number columns then you click on the one you want and it show you the entire row: Category, OEM Number, and Price. I do not want it to show the price for more than one item at a time.

Comment: I have seen a page do something similar to what I am trying to do. When you searched it showed the results in a table. The table showed 5 results per page and you could click an arrow or page number to show multiples of 5 results at a time. Those results just showed Category and OEM Number. Then you clicked on the specific one you wanted and it would show a page with the Category, OEM Number, Price, and picture if one was available. It looked like maybe they were using the datatables for it. Any suggestions or pointing me in the right direction to do this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @DeviantlyD Ah, then try showing detail when `results.length === 1`, show list when `results.length > 1` then users will have to narrow it down.

Comment: So are you saying I should replace my fetch with the getData? Or did you just do that to make it get your dummy data? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: @DeviantlyD I changed the name from `fetch` to `getData` because `fetch` is a built in function. You generally want to avoid name conflicts like that, but particularly here as the built in `fetch` is what you want to call download your data. I replaced it with dummy data so the example would run even though we can't access your service from the script snippets on here.

Comment: As I said I am new to this, so where it says "if (results.length > 0)" if I made that "if (results.length === 1)" then at the bottom add an else rows category and oemnumber type thing,that would work?

Comment: @DeviantlyD yes. Use `===1` for the check that renders one item in detail, `>=1` for a list of items, and anything  else is nothing found.